# partially test value of object property inside array using jasmine

Tags: angular, jasmine

I have a PopupComponent that i am trying to test using Jasmine. I have a form with multiple Formcontrols inside of  my PopupComponent, which will add an entry to a FormArray.

So i am trying to test, if the inserted values in my form are correctly saved inside the formarray. Problem is, if i add an entry, it will auto generate a UUID for me, which i don't want to test.

Let's say I Have the following entry inside my Formarray:

```
{
uuid: 'd3d354c9-ad70-4bef-9b40-e30047f1e203'
age: '23'
name: 'John'
job: 'Software Engineer'
}
```

This is what i tried:

```
expect(values).toEqual([{
age: '23'
name: 'John'
job: 'Software Engineer'}]);
```

Obviously i get a erorr, that uuid is missing. How can i partially test the values without uuid?
I have looked into `jasmine.arrayContaining` and `jasmine.objectContaining` but it didn't help me. Maybe I was using it wrong.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I rarely use `arrayContaining` or `objectContaining`. I tend to default to JavaScript in these kind of situations by using `.some`, `.every`, `for loop`, etc.

```
expect(theArray.some(value => value.age === '23' && value.name === 'John' && value.job === 'Software Engineer')).toBeTrue();
```

Something like the above. Of course, you can use a `for loop` or `forEach` loop as well. The idea is to boil it down to JavaScript and then do your assertion on what was obtained using JavaScript.

**Edit**
You can use `lodash` to see if an object is a subset of another object: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49807621/7365461

You can also create a custom function like this user did here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61676007/7365461

You can do:

```
expect(_.isMatch(theObj, subsetObj)).toBeTrue();
```

TypeScript is pretty much JavaScript but more strict.

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem for me! I am working with  Typescript, but i guess that does not make a big of a difference. I would still appreciate a cleaner solution (if there is one), since I need to check more properties than I have mentioned in my question.

Comment: Check out my edit.